# DISQUS comments in asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, comments, webforms, disqus

Hi i want to use [DISQUS](http://disqus.com/) comments system. But i couldnt find any resource for C# asp.net webforms, examples , source code or implement. I have found a project in [codeplex](http://disqusforwebpages.codeplex.com/) and [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/559728/An-Introduction-to-Disqus-Pluggable-Commenting-Sys)
 but it seems that the code is in MVC i haven't used MVC .
 Where can i find DISQUS implementation code in Asp.net C# webforms? not MVC.

Answer (score 4):

In most cases implementing Disqus into a website is really easy, since you're not actually building all the markup. At the minimum, you just need to add the [Universal Code](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472097-universal-embed-code) on the proper page templates, which links to the embed javascript file and the "disqus_thread" DIV.

At that point to make a "complete" integration, you just need to output some [javascript configuration variables](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472098-javascript-configuration-variables) (using a unique identifier, URL, and title for each thread) and maybe the [comment counting script](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/565624) and that should be it.

The only webforms-specific examples you might possibly need are how to output the article's unique ID, title and URL variables onto the page. So if you have a good idea of how to do that, you shouldn't need an existing integration.